# Fake proof of weak convergence $\implies$ strong convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

***Fake pf***: Let $X$ a Banach space, then let $x_n$ converge weakly to $x$, then as $X^* $ norms $X$
it follows that there exits some $ f \in X^*$ such that

$$ ||x_n - x|| = f(x_n-x) = f(x_n) - f(x) $$

by weak convergence $f(x_n) \to f(x) \implies f(x_n) - f(x) \to 0 $

---

I know this is wrong since the standard schauder basis in $\ell^p$ converges weakly but not strongly, I just do not know where the proof above went wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: $f$ depends on $n.$

Comment: Well, the claim $\exists f\in X^*,\forall n, f(x_n-x)=\lVert x_n-x\rVert$ is quite bold.

Comment: ah ofc thank you very much @RyszardSzwarc